# Single stroke font letters disappear when I export from Illustrator to Auto-cad

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, vector, export, autocad

I have a file in Illustrator with text on a path. The font is a single stroke text. I am wanting to use this to engrave with a machine so I can't have the font be outlined. When I export it to auto-cad the letters i, l and the dot on j disappear. How can I keep those letters from not showing up, without creating outlines. Any suggestions?

Link to where I got the font: http://imajeenyus.com/computer/20150110_single_line_fonts/index.shtml

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Illustrator uses a font engine that is not capable of doing single line fonts. All fonts in illustrator are outlines no matter what. If we take **CNC Vector** as an example its simply a outline that turns up on itself, so it is not truly a singe line font as far as illustrator or your cad is concerned. So beware if you use a cnc machine/ laser cutter the area will be machined 2 times.

As such the fonts you get out of illustrator will always be outlined. But if you preprocess the fonts and eliminate the inner loops then you can export them. Also if you do not use illustrators font engine then its also possible. But in both these cases they cease to be fonts as such.

Same applies to your dots cad software have usually no feeling of line thickness in default views so a infinitely small point is invisible but the vertices are still there. How the cutter reacts to this is another thing.

I would say its not agood idea to use illustrator for the job at all.

Comment: Thank you @joojaa that is very helpful. Now I understand why it doesn't work. What would you recommend using instead of illustrator?

Comment: @Emily Autocad?

Comment: I don't have access to autocad. The company we are using only uses that software for there machines. Any other compatible with exporting to autocad?

Comment: @Emily well you can stroke the fonts manually as lines but then its not text as such.